# Is $A=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}: x^2 + y^2 \le 1 \}$ compact and complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is $A=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2 \le 1 \}$ compact and complete metric space in $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_c)$ where$$ d_c:A\times A\to\mathbb R,(x,y) \mapsto \begin{cases} d_e(x,y) &\text{if $x,y$ and $0$ are collinear}  \\ d_e(x,0) + d_e(y,0) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

where $d_e(x,y)$ is euclidean metric.

I suppose that $A$ isn't compact space because from series $x_n = (- \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{2})$ we can not find a convergent subsequence, because $d_c(x_m,x_n) \ge 1$. Is it true?

What about completeness? I have no idea.

Comment: I don't understand: "if $x,y, 0$ in one line".

Comment: @julien: I think Tomek means "if $x$, $y$, and $0$ are collinear".

Comment: @julien: I think he means that you can only "move" along a line that passes through $0$ so if $y\in(0x)$ then, you can just "move" from $x$ to $y$ in a straight line and if not, you have to go all the way to $0$ using $(x0)$ and then go to $y$ using $(0y)$.

Comment: @julien: There is a $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, such that $x=\lambda y$ or $y=\lambda x$. This metric is sometimes referred to as "French railway" metric: Assume $A$ is France and Paris lies at zero. Now any point in France is connected to Paris by a direct railway line and there are no other lines. Hence, if two cities are not on a line with Paris, you need to take the detour via Paris.

Comment: So now all is clear?

Comment: Yeah, now it is clear, sorry for the slowness...

Comment: Your example to disprove compactness looks good. Another natural choice would be $x_n=(\cos(1/n),\sin(1/n))$.

Comment: @Tomek, it might be better to rename $x$ and $y$ in the definition of the metric to $P$ and $Q$, to avoid confusion between coordinates (in $\mathbb R$) and points (in $A \subseteq \mathbb R^2$).

Comment: I think that now is clear. What do you think about complete these set?

Comment: For completeness, note that $d_e(x,y)\leq d_c(x,y)$ for every $x,y$.

Comment: Ok I see it. But I suppose that I should find Cauchy sequence which is not corvengent to element which is in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a roadmap to completeness. I used uppercase letters in subscripts for better readability.

1. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence with respect to $d_C$.
2. Since $d_E\le d_C$, it follows that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy with respect to $d_E$.
3. Hence, there is $x\in A$ such that $d_E(x_n,x)\to 0$.
4. If $x=0$ then  $d_C(x_n,x)=d_E(x_n,x)$ and you are done.
5. If $x\ne 0$, then $d_E(x_n,0)\to d_E(x,0)>0$. It follows that for all large enough $n,m$ the points $0,x_n,x_m$ are collinear. Hence, $0,x ,x_n$ are collinear. Again, $d_C(x_n,x)=d_E(x_n,x)$ and you are done.

Comment: I don't understand point 5. Why you consider $d_E(x_n,0)$? I think that we should consider it more generally with $d_E(x_n,y)$. Furthermore, you have never use fact, that we consider subspace $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ so you have proved that metric space $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_C)$ is complet?

Comment: @Tomek To arrive at the second conclusion in 5. If $0,x_n,x_m$ are not collinear, then $d_C(x_n,x_m)\ge d_E(x_n,0)$. Here  $d_C(x_n,x_m)$ gets small but $d_E(x_n,0)$ does not.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try it. If $A$ is not complete. So there exists a Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}\subset (\mathbb{R}^2, d_c)$ such that $\{x_n\}$ has a limit $x_0$ that is not in $A$. That is $\|x_0\|>1$.

It is clearly $d_e\leq d_c$, then $x_n\to x_0$ in the $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_e)$. This implies that $\|x_0\|\leq 1$. A contradiction.

So $A$ is not compact but complete in $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_c)$

Comment: Could you tell me why $\|x_0\|>1$ ?

Comment: since $x_0\not\in A$, then $d_e(x_0,0)>1$, that is, $\|x_0\|>1$.

Comment: Roughly speaking, I think if $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy, if it is not colinear for large $n$, then $x_n\to 0$. But, now, I do not know whether it is right.

Comment: Lack of completeness does not mean "there is a Cauchy sequence with limit that is not in the space". It means "there is a Cauchy sequence that does not have a limit [in the metric of the space]".